# Git Can't Push Linked to Old Account

Tags: git, github

```
$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to xxx/test.git denied to OLDUSER.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/test.git/': The requested URL
returned error: 403
```

this problem occurs after I changed my git user into the new one.
It's like that I can't push with my current user because it's still linked with old account. How do I fix this?

what i've already done:

- create new ssh
- update config user & email
- my user already authenticated with github account (ssh -T git@github.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ssh keys won't matter if you are using an https url.
Check your exact url with git remote -v.

If it is an https one, force the new username account in it:

```
git remote set-url https://<newusername>@github.com/<newusername>/yourRepo
```

Note that if you are pushing to a repo not directly owned by newusername, like your "old account", you would need to go to:

- either that repo and add `<newusername>` as a collaborator
- or git push --all your current local cloned repo to a new empty `yourRepo` created with `newusername` GitHub account.

Comment: it's all new, i created repository from new github account, then i cloned it into my local, but cannot push.
your way is not working.

Comment: I try it once again with set-url using ssh link and now it's working.
But what's the meaning of this?

Comment: @user3045529 by using the ssh url, it must be using the right account.